# Uncompressed files by content double gzipped by mistake

Tags: bash, ubuntu, compression, gzip

I have some files that I gzipped twice by mistake **with no file extension**

For example `gzip -dc file` outputs some binary gibberish for some of the files and for some other files it's okay

I would like to run a command to be able to find the double gzipped files in a folder (not all of them are double gzipped, but all of them are at least once) and automatically revert them to a single gzipping state

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```bsh
for file in *; do 
    zcat -- "$file" | 
        file - | 
            grep -wq compressed && 
                gunzip -- "$file"
done
```

This has the advantage of being able to run on arbitrary file names (unlike [your approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/647316/22222) with `ls`, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and it also seems considerably simpler. To my eye, at least.

The disadvantage is that you could end up with gzipped files without the `.gz` extension. But that's easy enough to fix:

```bsh
for file in *; do 
    case "$file" in 
        *.gz) ;; 
        *) file -- "$file" | 
            grep -wq compressed && 
                mv -v -- "$file" "$file".gz;; 
    esac
done
```

Comment: Didn't know about `zcat` quite useful, but I don't think the last bit works, gunzip fails if the file doesn't have a .gz extension

Comment: @Tofandel there's a whole family of them! There's very rarely any reason to actually store a decompressed file. You have `zcat`, `zmore`, `zgrep`, `bzcat` and probably others.

Comment: Yep `gzip: some_file unknown suffix -- ignored`

Comment: @Tofandel yes, you can fix that with the second command. Or even modify the first to `for file in *; do zcat -- "$file" | file - | grep -wq compressed && zcat -- "$file" > /tmp/foo && mv /tmp/foo "$file"; done`

Comment: I think you still have to move the file to a .gz one and then run it, otherwise the file attributes are lost

Comment: Basically `grep -wq compressed && mv "$file" "$file.gz" && gunzip -- "$file.gz"`

Comment: I think you missed the fact that the files don't have a `.gz` extension at all, but the workaround of adding it and ungzipping works

Comment: @Tofandel I had indeed. Your edit helps, but it would be even better if you could add some example files. Are you saying that _none_ of these have `.gz` extensions? Also, what operating system and what shell are you using? Can we assume GNU tools and bash?

Comment: Yep, none have .gz extension, I'm using bash on ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Here is the command I used:

```bsh
ls | xargs -L1 -I[] sh -c 'basename "[]" | xargs -L1 -I{} sh -c "cp -a \"[]\" \"/tmp/{}.gz\" && gzip -d \"/tmp/{}.gz\" && file \"/tmp/{}\" | (grep compressed -q && rsync -a \"/tmp/{}\" \"[]\" --remove-source-files) || rm \"/tmp/{}\""'
```

It basically copies the file to `/tmp/` uncompressing it once, checks if that new file is still compressed (`file some_file | grep compressed -q`), if it is, moves it back to its original location (`rsync source dest --remove-source-files`), if not, deletes the temp file